# SQL query to check if a select operation returns rows

Tags: sql, oracle, unix

I need to check if the `select` operation I am performing is returning any rows or not.
Can someone please help me with this.

I am working on a shell script so I cannot save it in a variable and check. I need to check on the fly. I know I can use the count switch. But can someone help me with the syntax?

For example, I need to check:

```
--Now this query should return some data
select * from error_repository_BKP partition(part_maxval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) from error_repository_BKP partition(part_maxval);
```

??

Answer (score 0):

```
If exists (Select 1 from error_repository_BKP partition(part_maxval))
  Begin
      print 'returns Row'
  End
Else
  Begin
      Print 'No Rows' 
  End
```

??